# how do i call the controller in kendo ui grid mvc

Tags: kendo-ui-mvc

How do i call the controller in mvc kendoui grid

here is the code:

but not working:

```
   .ClientTemplate(string.Format("<a class=\"modal\" rel=\"/address/#= Id #/map\" close=\"{0}\" title=\"{1}\"><img src=\"/content/images/ico_edit_16.png\" /></a>",
                                T("Common.Close").Text,
                                T("Address.MapAddress").Text)
```

here is the controller:

```
  public ActionResult AddressMap( int accountId)
    {
        //load default accounts
        var listModel = new AddressListModel();
        //{
        //    AccountId = accountId,
        //    GridPageSize = _commonSettings.GridPageSize,
        //};

        //listModel.Addresses = new List<AddressModel>();
        return View(listModel);
    }
```

Comment: you are not setting the `href` of the link from what I can see. also are you expecting this link to load a navigate away from the current page or load a `modal` or another part of the screen?

Comment: how do i setting..can you tell me??

Comment: is the url always going to be same or will it change depending on the model being provided?

Comment: the url going to be error on this conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing code:

```
   .ClientTemplate(string.Format("<a class=\"modal\" rel=\"/address/#= Id #/map\"    
                     close=\"{0}\" title=\"{1}\"><img src=\"/content/images/ico_edit_16.png\" /></a>",
                                T("Common.Close").Text,
                                T("Address.MapAddress").Text)
```

You will see you are setting the `a` tag's rel setting rather than the `href` property.

so all you should need to do is change the tag so it is more like this:

```
(string.Format("<a class='k-link' href='{2}' close='{0}' title='{1}'><img src='/content/images/ico_edit_16.png' />#=Id#</a>",
                                    T("Common.Close").Text,
                                    T("Address.MapAddress").Text, @Url.Action("AddressMap", "{Your Controller}", new {accountId= "#=Id#"})))
```

All I have done is passed the url into the string formatter and then bound the `accountId` to the Id that is passed into the row from the dataItem.

I have also added the Id to the link so you can see what is being presented.

If this isn't what you wanted then let me know what you actually need and I will amend the answer accordingly

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Account/AddressMap

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.81.0

Comment: all you need to do is change the url so it matches your controllers signature. In the example provided you used `accountId` and the parameter but in the provided comment above you are using `addressId`

Comment: now i hit the controller..i want to show the address in amap can you tell me any idea??

Comment: That all depends on you I guess and how you want the user experience to be. I would suggest looking into using a map service provider like google, openstreetmaps, bing etc. then using their framework for loading your data onto the map. If you look here http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/map/index there are some examples for you

Comment: in .Center(30.268107, -97.744821) i want to pass the model value so can you tell what should i write and how to declare model in this view page??

Comment: i have declare the model in the top of the page @model AccountAddressEditModel

Comment: how can i access in 30.268107 and -97.744821 values

Comment: just add the values to your model and then access them using the `@model.{your property here}`

Comment: This really is now going away from the scope of this question so please ask another question.

Comment: Sir can you tell me how to use a google map on kendo ui view page in mvc??